# Creating Kagi Chart with Highcharts/Highstocks

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have Highcharts integrated into my project and would like to create Kagi chart. It looks similar to Step Line chart, however, the thickness/thinness of the lines cannot be handled as currently highcharts doesn't provide any such options.

Is there any way to tweak the Step Line chart or any available charts in highcharts to create Kagi chart shown on StockCharts (http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:chart_analysis:kagi)?

Need a quick solution for my problem.

Thank you!

Comment: You could use multiple series - one for the thicker line and one for the thinner line?

Comment: I agree with @wergeld - the most obvious way to do this would be with a separate series for each thickness of line. The series could all be grouped, so that there would be one legend entry

Comment: Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gmo29s40/

Comment: @morganfree Maybe the chart in the fiddle won't be correct as the wide & narrow lines need to be manipulated on the basis of the trough & peak for a kagi chart.